# Adding controls to winform while allowing user to enter input

Tags: winforms, multithreading, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I have a WinForms data entry form that will have upwards of 1500 questions.  I have the questions broken into sections, and each section will have an unkown number of questions.  Each section is its own user control and has rows (2 panels, 2 labels, a textbox, and another user control) created and added dynamically for each question.  The section controls are then added to the form.

My problem is that the process takes a lot of time, even with using TPL (Task Parallel Library).  I would ultimately like to create/add the controls and allow the user to start entering data at the same time.  The controls are going into a scrollable panel.  While the user is entering data, that data will need processed on a local database...so more threading could be necessary.

I have tried working with TPL, which I am new to, by having all the controls added to a list during processing and then sorted and added to the form after the `Parallel.ForEach` was complete...takes about 20 seconds for over 1200 questions.

I also tried utilizing a `BackgroundWorker` component.  Using the BWC seems to be the faster of the two, but there is a race condition for the `ProgressChanged()` eventhandler and not all controls get added...not to mention the way the form looks with all the rerendering.

Am i just using TPL wrong?  What's the best way to go about this?  Is there another way or do I just make the user stick out the wait?

Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with threading.  It simply takes that long to just paint the form when you have this many controls.  It is too large by a factor of well over 10.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Yes, I concur that the form is too large. Unfortunately, it's something that's out of my control.

Comment: This is heading for project disaster.  At least let the stake-holder know what he's to expect.  The 'not my problem' attitude makes nobody happy, it will be made your problem.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I never said that I was taking the 'not my problem' attitude. Everyone is fully aware of the issue and that this is not good practice. As you can see, it's already my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am i just using TPL wrong? What's the best way to go about this? Is there another way or do I just make the user stick out the wait?

Most likely, you can use TPL, and get the same response time as BW, but a nicer API for this type of operation.

The trick here is to get a TaskScheduler setup for UI interaction, and then use the Task class to push the controls back onto the UI thread as they're ready.  I have a [blog post on this specific subject](http://reedcopsey.com/2010/03/18/parallelism-in-net-part-15-making-tasks-run-the-taskscheduler/) which shows how to get a TaskScheduler setup to use with UI threads.

However, I would recommend keeping these in memory and pushing them in batches, to avoid constantly re-rendering the UI.  This is likely to be an issue no matter what you're doing.

That being said - I'd question your overall visual design here - if you're trying to display over 1200 questions to the user, some form of paging is probably a much nicer approach than a huge scrollable container.  If you page these, you could load and process the first few (which is probably near instantaneous, since you mentioned you can process about 50 questions/second), and then continue loading the others after the first few questions have been displayed.

Comment: I do agree that a better UI design would be to break up the sections, which was my suggestion, but specs and clients dictate otherwise.

Comment: @jonnyltunes: Then I'd recommend using Task/Task<T> and batching.  My blog post above (and the couple entries preceeding it) show the basic approach.

Comment: @Reed Copsey: Nice blog posts! I followed your blog and get the controls marshelled to the UI thread. However, it seems that despite creating a `Task` for the process of creating the controls and using `BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke`, the main thread is still blocked. Any ideas? I even put a thread sleeper in to break up the processing.

Comment: @Jonnyltunes: How are you starting the task?  are you calling Task.Wait() or Task.Result? [that blocks...]

Comment: @Reed Copsey: Thanks for responding. I created a `TaskScheduler` using `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` and a `new TaskFactory(uiScheduler)`. Then I call `uiTaskFactory.StartNew(() => ProcessSections(Sections));` Sections is a list object that was generated prior to this step. At this point, I am just trying to create the controls and add them to a Queue, without adding any to the Form, and the main thread is still blocked. I do not use `Task.Wait()` or `Task.Result`. The items in my Sections list are a combo of properties and `EntityObjects`.

Comment: @jonnyltunes: When you call TaskFactory.StartNew - it's still pushing the "ProcessSections" method onto the UI thread, so it'll block until that completes.  You need to load as much of this as possible in teh background thread, then only do the UI work on the UI thread as you go...